# Is it really correct to declare all instance attributes in __init__

Tags: python

According to Pycharm (and thus assume according by PEP) i should state all instance attributes directly inside `__init__`. In my case it does not seem suitable to me. I have something like:

```
class Handler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_index = # parse
        # Do stuff

    def parse(self):
        parse_header()
        # Do stuff
        parse_body()

    def parse_header():
        raise NotImplementedError

    def parse_body():
        raise NotImplementedError


class StringHandler(Handler):
    def parse_header():
        self.string_index = # parse
        self.string_count = # parse
        self.style_index = # parse
        self.style_count = # parse
        # More here

    def parse_body():
        self.strings = # parse
        self.styles = # parse
        # More here


class IntHandler(Handler):
    def parse_header():
        self.int_index = # parse
        self.int_count = # parse
        # More here

    def parse_body():
        self.ints = # parse
        # More here
```

Given that there are objects (quite a lot of them) that all derive from `Handler` class, the structure of each object it quite obvious for anyone who reads the code. To me it seems like unnecessary cluttering to declare `__init__` just for sake of calling parent `__init__` and declare couple of parameters as `None`. Usually `parse`-ing functions just parse whatever is needed and store that to attributes, thus adding such `__init__` would sometimes almost double the size of the class (code-wise).

edit: I searched for this problem, but I did not found suitable answer, for example while searching stackexcahnge, the questions were either too broad to get useful answer ( [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code) ) or asking different question ( [Is it a good practice to declare instance variables as None in a class in Python?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254576/is-it-a-good-practice-to-declare-instance-variables-as-none-in-a-class-in-python) )

Comment: It would be lovely to have comment for that -1 so I can avoid the same mistake again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code)

Comment: @gnat I believe the question you are referring to is way to broad, I was trying to be specific enough to get reasonable opinion of more experienced people

Comment: I wonder if SO could implement a check that anyone who is attempting -1 has at least one comment. Or perhaps it may be better to just pop up a tool tip to advise "when voting down please explain your reasons in a comment so that the OP can learn, and your down vote is not interpreted as just abusive".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you should assign all attributes of your object in the `__init__` method.

The most important reason to do this is tool support. Many Python IDEs can see the assignments in the `__init__` and use those attributes for type-based autocompletion. Sphinx-doc can list those attributes in your reference documentation.

There's also a more fundamental reason: Simple is good, so don't create complicated objects that change their shape during execution. Given a `StringHandler` instance I may or may not be able to read the `handler.strings` attribute. If I try that before `handler.parse()` has been executed, I will get an `AttributeError`. Afterwards I would get the value. To avoid exceptions, consumers of your class would have to `getattr(handler, 'strings', None)` with a default value which is quite tedious.

In general, constructors should create fully-initialized objects that are immediately usable. In some cases it is necessary to create mutable objects that have an empty, default state, and later transition to a state where they contain a value. However, this should be the exception and is rarely a good design. See also [Are init() methods a code smell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/334970) and [Start Method vs. Setting up everything in constructor](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/334162) which discuss this issue for Java.

In your case the `parse()` method is such a two-phase initialization method that must be called before the object can really be used. This raises the questions:

- What is the point of these objects, if they're just a container for whatever values the `parse()` function produces? As you are using them, you might as well use a dict instead of a class.
- Is an empty `Handler` meaningful in any way?
- Why is the initialization in `parse()` separate from the other initialization?
- Or are you using those attributes only for communication between the `parse_x` functions, not for external consumers?

Possible alternative designs:

- The handlers specify how a field should be parsed, but do not actually contain the value. The `parse` method returns the value. Because the handlers do not contain any data, it  may not be necessary to use classes for this – simple functions could are sufficient.
- The handlers represent a parsed value. There is no “empty” state. The parsing either happens in the constructor, or in separate functions. Because these objects are just dumb structs, you could define them via `namedtuple()` when parsing is separate.

Comment: While I cannot agree with your "main" reason -- In my mind IDE capabilities should not affect your code design, overall answer is really nice and comprehensive! Just for clarification - answer to many of your remarks is that the shown sample is minimal working example and the actual code is a little more complex.

Comment: @Drecker why not? It is not for the benefit of the IDE, but the *user* of the IDE, the future maintainer. They should influence your design.

Comment: As of 3.3, with [PEP 412: Key-Sharing Dictionaries](https://peps.python.org/pep-0412/), the CPython reference interpreter rewards you for always initializing all fields in `__init__` (even if some of them are just initialized to placeholders like `None`) by roughly halving the memory overhead of each instance when that guideline is followed.

Comment: Agree that IDEs should follow our code, not we should care about IDEs (my IDE is vim). "Simple is good, so don't create complicated objects that change their shape during execution." - simple is good, so don't create attributes just to replace them an instant later. Also, if you create attributes with *None*, how do you assure that it is not a valid value.

Answer (score 1):

Counter example to the existing expected "Yes" answer:

When you develop a GUI having, let's say, 30 widgets (where lot of them could be just simple parent containers), it is too ugly to code 30 instance attributes (widget instances) within the initializer. In fact, on many levels, it is not even practical to do that within `__init__()`. I always "delay" the creation of widgets by delegating them to a dedicated function which, in turn, can rely on other smaller functions each having a responsibility on this or that group of widgets.

Comment: While I agree that the `__init__` can certainly get too large, I would only delegate the initialization but not the attribute assignment to other functions. I.e. in the constructor: `self.lower_left_widget = MyGui.make_lower_left_widget(args)`

Comment: IMHO, that is not practical. Here is an [example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176298/feynmann-lifeguard-riddle-graphical-representation/176327#176327)

Comment: I strongly disagree there. I've looked at your example and am unimpressed. All those attributes that would be “not practical” to assign? Most of them are totally unneeded: and only the sand/sea area and the lifeguard, child, sand speed scales are ever used after initialization. Why keep the rest around? Your misguided focus on niladic functions has led you to effectively write procedural code that communicates through global variables. That data flow is unnecessarily difficult to follow. I'd write it like this: https://gist.github.com/latk/d72c89b89f6fcc3ee8a1a93719972387

Answer (score 0):

One counter-example is when you use a function to reset properties, avoiding duplicated code:

```
class Handler(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.resetProperties()

  def resetProperties(self, prop1=None, prop2=None):
    self._prop1 = prop1
    self._prop2 = prop2
```

Comment: Why do you call *self.resetProperties()* in *init*?