# Assigning to fields in function or by function?

Tags: class, readability, constructors, properties

While writing the constructor for class `A` in Python, I calculate some of the class's fields using function `fun()`. This function is never used outside the constructor of instances of this class.
In situations like these, I tend to write `fun()` so that it returns the desired values and then I assign these values in the initialization, like so:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = self.fun(2)

    def fun(self, i: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
        return i**2, i**3
```

This to me seems clear in that the constructor clearly shows which fields are created.

A different approach would have these fields be assigned to inside `fun()`, like so:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fun(2)

    def fun(self, i: int):
        self.a = i**2
        self.b = i**3
```

I feel like this second method hinders readability because to see what fields are created or assigned to, I have to inspect `fun()`. However, maybe I'm missing something.

Is there any reason to prefer the second method over the first? Or are there any more reasons to prefer method one other than readability?

This question occurred to me while writing Python, but is not restricted to the Python language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it really correct to declare all instance attributes in \_\_init\_\_](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/357937/is-it-really-correct-to-declare-all-instance-attributes-in-init)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = fun(2)
```

Yes, I agree with you.
Prefer that style.

Why?
The `__init__` ctor should offer the Gentle Reader a convenient
summary of the `public` and `_private` attributes that affect
the object's behavior.
You are exactly right that asking a maintenance engineer to
peruse diverse methods beyond `__init__` to understand
what attributes *might* be defined over an object's lifetime
is unreasonable. It will impact maintainability.

Additionally, breaking out complex logic as you did
is good for readability of the constructor,
and good for anyone who wants to write small unit tests.
I would only amend it to `def _fun`, indicating it is private.

Conventionally we use a placeholder value of `None`
if we're not quite ready to immediately find a "real" value.

Comment: If the goal is readability, suggest putting self.y on a second line

Comment: @AdamB, I disagree. Returning a tuple makes perfect sense, and an `a, b, c = ...` tuple unpack is the pythonic way to approach it. The alternative would be to insist that a helper return just a single scalar, which in some contexts would harm rather than help readability. // In the many projects that choose to adopt [black](https://pypi.org/project/black), insisting on the multi-line expression that you suggest would be a non-starter.